# Force XmlSerializer to use &#38; instead of &amp;?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

With the .Net XmlSerializer, is it possible to force it to escape the ampersand as `&#38;` instead of the default `&amp;`?

It seems I might be dealing with a so-called XML recipient beyond my control which does handle unicode-based character entities, but has problems with some of the five standard entities defined by XML.

Comment: No, this is hard-coded in the XmlTextEncoder class.  Internal, and the XmlTextWriter.xmlEncoder field is private, you can't override it.